# No module named social.pipeline.social_auth

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I'm trying to live my django social auth website on linux server, after google login it's showing error(No module named social.pipeline.social_auth). How can I fix this ?

Website url :- http://nam.woo.gy

Comment: please include code and traceback in question

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of  pipeline used to  complete process (redirected after confirmation on social account). It's simply coused by wrong imports. Please try to import it in few different ways in   django shell (`python manage.py shell`). Check also if  you got proper project  structure based on example: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/example